# How to use multiple kinects on the same USB 2.0 bus

Tags: ros, kinect, usb, driver, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I got two questions about kinect driver (OpenNI,freeKinect under Ubuntu or even Kinect SDK under windows, what ever works. Kinect here refers to Kinect for Xbox, not Kinect for windows which is more expensive but support up to 4 kinect on same PC)

Al though I got 3 independent USB 2.0 BUS, when I connect 2 Kinects to my PC, they always goes to the same USB BUS

1 is it possible to shut down Kinect_1 temporarily, to get IR streams from Kinect_2 on the same USB bus? For example, I want to do the 3D 360 degree scan, and I need 3 kinects to work together, but I only need them to work in 3 frames (which lasts about 0.1 second), each gives out 1 frame of point cloud.

2 is it possible to reduce the information that sent from kinect to PC, so that I can use several kinect at the same time without any one of them using up the bandwidth? For example, to do the 3D 360 degree scan, I only need 3 different point clouds from 3 different angles of the same object, but not anything else like RGB stream.

part of my lsusb results(to make sure I really had 3 usb 2.0 bus on my laptop):

---

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31735/how-to-use-multiple-kinects-on-the-same-usb-2.0-bus/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, this would require modifying some stuff in openni_camera. Perhaps eventually USB3.0 will be supported and we won't have to worry about saturating a single USB bus anymore.

If you do end up modifying the driver to meet your needs in a reusable way, make sure to submit a patch. I'm sure this sort of thing would be useful to others.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0